# Getting DataContext error while saving form

Tags: linq, datacontext

I get this error when opening one specific form. The rest is working fine and I have no clue why this one isn't.

Error: An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext.  This is not supported.

I get the error at _oDBConnection when I try to save. When I watch _oDBConnection while running through the code, it does not exist. Even when I open the main-window it does not exist. So this form is where the DataContext is built for the very first time.

Every class inherits from clsBase where the DataContext is built.

My collegue is the professional one who built it all. I am just expanding and using it (learned it by doing it). But now I'm stuck and he is on holiday. So keep it simple :-)

What can it be?

clsPermanency

```
namespace Reservation
{
    class clsPermanency : clsBase
    {
        private tblPermanency _oPermanency;

        public tblPermanency PermanencyData
        {
            get { return _oPermanency; }
            set { _oPermanency = value; }
        }

        public clsPermanency()
            : base()
        {
            _oPermanency = new tblPermanency();
        }       
        public clsPermanency(int iID)
            : this()
        {
            _oPermanency = (from oPermanencyData in _oDBConnection.tblPermanencies
                            where oPermanencyData.ID == iID
                            select oPermanencyData).First();

            if (_oPermanency == null)
                throw new Exception("Permanentie niet gevonden");
        }

        public void save()
        {
            if (_oPermanency.ID == 0)
            {
                _oDBConnection.tblPermanencies.InsertOnSubmit(_oPermanency);
            }
            _oDBConnection.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

clsBase

```
public class clsBase
{
    protected DBReservationDataContext _oDBConnection;
    protected int _iID;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _iID; }
    }

    public DBReservationDataContext DBConnection
    {
        get { return _oDBConnection; }
    }

    public clsBase()
    {
        _oDBConnection = new DBReservationDataContext();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but this is really bad design, sorry.

Issues:

1. **One context instance per class instance**. Pretty incredible. How are you going to manage units of work and transactions? And what about memory consumption and performance?
2. **Indirection**: every entity instance (prefixed `o`) is wrapped in a `cls` class. What a hassle to make classes cooperate, if necessary, or to access their properties.
3. **DRY**: far from it. Does each `clsBase` derivative have the same methods as `clsPermanency`?
4. **Constructors**: you always have to call the base constructor. The constructor with `int iID` always causes a redundant `new` object to be created, which will certainly be a noticeable performance hit when dealing with larger numbers. A minor change in constructor logic may cause the sequence of constructor invocations to change. (Nested and inherited constructors are always tricky).
5. **Exception handling**: you need a try-catch everywhere where classes are created. (BTW: `First()` will throw its own exception if the record is not there).

Finally, not a real issue, but class and variable name prefixes are sooo 19xx.

### What to do?

- I don't think you can change your colleague's design in his absence. But I'd really talk to him about it in due time. Just study some linq-to-sql examples out there to pick up some regular patterns.
- The exception indicates that somewhere between fetching the `_oPermanency` instance (in the Id-d constructor) and saving it a new `_oDBConnection` is created. The code as shown does not reveal how this could happen, but I assume there is more code than this. When you debug and check GetHashCode() of `_oDBConnection` instances you should be able to find where it happens.

Comment: thx for your honesty. I can only reply on the first and last point, the other ones are rising above my knowledge. I worked with a static DataContext first but while using 2 instances of the programm simultaneously, altered data in one instance was not being reloaded in the other one. LINQ was retrieving the old values stored in the cache. Newly added records ones were loaded. On the 5th point: yes, that I know...

Comment: Yes, a static context is bad, so that's one good design decision :D. I hope debugging will reveal something. Hell of a job to fix someone else's code.